# Creating Relationships Between Nodes in Neo4j with Neo4jClient in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm working with Neo4j using the .Net Neo4jClient (http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/Home). In my code, nodes are airports and relationships are flights.

If I want to create nodes and relationships at the same time, I can do it with the following code:

**Classes**

```
public class Airport
{
    public string iata { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class flys_toRelationship : Relationship, IRelationshipAllowingSourceNode<Airport>, IRelationshipAllowingTargetNode<Airport>
{
    public static readonly string TypeKey = "flys_to";

    // Assign Flight Properties
    public string flightNumber { get; set; }

    public flys_toRelationship(NodeReference targetNode)
        : base(targetNode)
    { }

    public override string RelationshipTypeKey
    {
        get { return TypeKey; }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
// Create a New Graph Object
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();

// Create New Nodes
var lax = client.Create(new Airport() { iata = "lax", name = "Los Angeles International Airport" });
var jfk = client.Create(new Airport() { iata = "jfk", name = "John F. Kennedy International Airport" });
var sfo = client.Create(new Airport() { iata = "sfo", name = "San Francisco International Airport" });

// Create New Relationships
client.CreateRelationship(lax, new flys_toRelationship(jfk) { flightNumber = "1" });
client.CreateRelationship(lax, new flys_toRelationship(sfo) { flightNumber = "2" });
client.CreateRelationship(sfo, new flys_toRelationship(jfk) { flightNumber = "3" });
```

The problem, however, is when I want to add relationships to already existing nodes. Say I have a graph consisting of only two nodes (airports), say SNA and EWR, and I would like to add a relationship (flight) from SNA to EWR. I try the following and it fails:

```
// Create a New Graph Object
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();

Node<Airport> departure = client.QueryIndex<Airport>("node_auto_index", IndexFor.Node, "iata:sna").First();
Node<Airport> arrival = client.QueryIndex<Airport>("node_auto_index", IndexFor.Node, "iata:ewr").First();
//Response.Write(departure.Data.iata); <-- this works fine, btw: it prints "sna"

// Create New Relationships
client.CreateRelationship(departure, new flys_toRelationship(arrival) { flightNumber = "4" });
```

The two errors I'm receiving are as follows:

1) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Neo4jClient.Node' to 'Neo4jClient.NodeReference'

2) The type arguments for method 'Neo4jClient.GraphClient.CreateRelationship(Neo4jClient.NodeReference, TRelationship)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The method the error is referring to is in the following class: http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/src/2c5446c17a65d6e5accd420a2dff0089799cbe16/Neo4jClient/GraphClient.cs?at=default

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Brent, could you please explain how you added the indexes onto the node? I created the index but I think I am missing something, my ``client.QueryIndex`` always returns null.. May be you could answer my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358797 Also, How did you figure out how to use the client.QueryIndex function? I couldn't find any documentation anywhere for it.. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer. Awesome! The documentation for the Neo4jClient is really "limited" right now so I, and I assume everyone else, had to spend hours searching this site as well the rest of the internet looking at working examples. Luckily for us, there are a lot of very helpful people here who have already been through it!

Comment: thank you, I am learning for myself, but it is a lot of trial and error.. I was thinking of contributing to the wiki once I understood the basic stuff.. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I have the same idea about the wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `CreateRelationship` call you will need to use the node references, not the nodes, so:

```
client.CreateRelationship(departure.Reference, new flys_toRelationship(arrival.Reference) { flightNumber = "4" });
```

The reason why your initial creation code works and this didn't is because `Create` returns you a `NodeReference<Airport>` (the `var` is hiding that for you), and the `QueryIndex` returns a `Node<Airport>` instance instead.

Neo4jClient predominantly uses `NodeReference`'s for the majority of its operations.

The second error you had was just related to not using the `.Reference` property as it couldn't determine the types, when you use the `.Reference` property that error will go away as well.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the answer as well as the very helpful explanation. This had been driving me crazy all day!

Comment: I found this blog and code to get me through: http://blog.micic.ch/net/using-neo4j-graph-db-with-c-net HTH